# Code always shows livestream as offline

Tags: php, json, api, request

my code suddenly stopped working for no known reason. I've double-checked the API response manually to see if the structure of the API has changed but it hasn't. There are no errors showing even with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled.

Maybe one of you can figure it out :)

This is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function hitbox($channel){
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/'.strtolower($channel)), true);
    $follower = $response['livestream'][0]['channel']['followers'];
    $viewer   = $response['livestream'][0]['media_views'];
    $Game     = $response['livestream'][0]['category_name'];

    if ($response['livestream'][0]['media_is_live'] == 1) {
        echo ("Hitbox: <span class='live'>Live</span><br>");
        echo ("Viewers: ".$viewer);
    } else {
        echo ("Hitbox: <span class='offline'>Offline</span>");
    }
}

function twitch($channel){
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/'.strtolower($channel)), true);
    $follower = $response['stream'][0]['channel']['followers'];
    $viewer   = $response['stream']['viewers'];

    if ($response['stream'] !== null) {
        echo ("Twitch: <span class='live'>Live</span><br>");
        echo ("Viewers: ".$viewer);
    } else {
        echo ("Twitch: <span class='offline'>Offline</span>");
    }
}

?>
```

Here is a live view of the response embedded at my main page:
http://www.kazuto.de/

Thanks in advance ^^

Comment: Never used Twitch or Hitbox APIs, do you have some sample JSON response from the APIs that I can look at?

Comment: Sure :)

Twitch response if online: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/yuuie
Twitch response if offline: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/kazutode

Hitbox response if online: http://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/wwgtv
Hitbox response if offline: http://api.hitbox.tv/media/live/kazuto

Comment: So, first question: this line '$follower = $response['stream'][0]['channel']['followers'];' gets the first element of a JSONArray, but there is no JSONArray in the JSON you provided ( $response['stream'] looks like an object to me ), you sure this is intended?

Comment: Also, you're accessing properties of the 'stream' object before checking if it is null, which could make your script crash before it completes...

Comment: But if I test your code manually, it works correctly. So the problem isn't with your code (even if accessing those non-existing properties is firing a few warnings on my end)

Comment: It worked so I never thought about it if it is right or wrong xD But I've placed the viewers etc. inside of the if clause when the media is live. It works now too again. For some reason the `allow_url_fopen` was disabled. I had to re-enable it and now it works again. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution. By the way, you may want to publish that as the answer to this question. For people that stumble upon a problem like this.